# Find Character in string and assign it to variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm using Python 2.7.3

I'm trying to assign the string `drive` a letter based on the multi-line string. The drive letter may always be different, and the indexing may also always be different on where the letter is.

In the following string, we can see the letter is `K`.

string = `Volume 2                      RAW    Partition      8 MB  Healthy\n    K:\XYZ\`

In this string, we can see the letter is `H`.

string2 = `Volume 2         NEW VOLUME   FAT    Partition      8 MB  Healthy\n    H:\XYZ\`

So far, I can use the following to see what the string is, but I'm not sure how to use replace to find the letter. (Hint: It would be something with `#four spaces here` + `.*` + `\\XYZ`)...

```
if re.search(r'.*Volume.*\n.*XYZ.*', mainLine):
    drive = mainLine.replace(r'.*Volume.*\n    .*:\\XYZ.*', )
    print drive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the following regex:

```
s = re.search(r'(\w):\\\w+', string).group(1)
s2 = re.search(r'(\w):\\\w+', string2).group(1)

>>> print s
K

>>> print s2
H
```

Your string will have to be as follows:

```
string = 'Volume 2                      RAW    Partition      8 MB  Healthy\n K:\XYZ\\'
string2 = 'Volume 2         NEW VOLUME   FAT    Partition      8 MB  Healthy\n    H:\XYZ\\'
```

[***DEMO***](http://repl.it/Rin/1)

Comment: Wow, it works like a charm. I don't know how or understand exactly parts of the line such as `(\w)` + `\w+` + `group(1)`. But it works!!!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there will always be exactly one ':' per source string, immediately following the drive letter:

```
drive = source[source.index(':') - 1]
```

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but I could say this is also true.